# How can I add metadata with Stripe createUsageRecord() to categorize usage on my end

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have a SaaS where a user can have multiple projects. Every 24h I'm reporting usage to Stripe because I have metered billing, but currently I have no way of getting usage for each individual project. I'm trying to avoid keeping that data in my own database and would like to utilize Stripe's usage reports, if that's at all possible.

Currently my code looks like this:

```js
const usageRecord = await stripe.subscriptionItems.createUsageRecord(
    'si_OgrBOJp9...',
    {
        quantity: 1, 
        timestamp: timestamp,
        metadata: { projectId: ... } // This doesn't work
    }
);
```

However when I try to add metadata to the usage record object, I get an error for unrecognized property. Here is what the Stripe docs say about metadata:

> Most updatable Stripe objects—including Account, Charge, Customer, PaymentIntent, Refund, Subscription, and Transfer—have a metadata parameter. You can use this parameter to attach arbitrary key-value data to these Stripe objects.

I'm guessing the usage record object is not updatable.

Is there any way to achieve this without using my own solution to keep usage records? Ultimately I want to be able to draw a chart of daily/monthly usage for each individual project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata is not supported for usage records:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create

> I'm guessing the usage record object is not updatable.

It's even worse than that = the usage records can't even be exported - at least not exactly how you recorded them.
All you can do is list subscription item summaries, which bundle your usage records:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/subscription_item_summary_list

Your best solution would be to store this information outside of Stripe (or on metadata stored on other objects like the Subscription).
Alternatively, if you want to show each record on your Customer's Invoice, you could do that with Invoice Items, however we're completely abandoning the metered usage system you are implementing here.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoiceitems/create

Comment: Got it, so a custom solution is my only option. I'm using Firebase anyway so I could think of a scheme to use Firestore efficiently.